# Django: how to link to static files dir from with .css file?

Tags: python, html, css, django, django-templates

i am trying to get access to my static images directory (/static/myapp/images/) from inside of a css file.

i initially tried this:

```
{% load staticfiles %}

#header {
    position:relative;
    width: 680px;
    height:99px;
    margin-left:29px;
    margin-right:21px;
    background: url({% static 'myapp/images/header.png' %}) no-repeat;
}
```

but this did not work

this however works fine:

```
#header {
    position:relative;
    width: 680px;
    height:99px;
    margin-left:29px;
    margin-right:21px;
    background: url(../images/header.png) no-repeat;
}
```

does Django template language work inside of css files?

or is it just my syntax, and lack of understanding off css! this css comes from a simple template i downloaded, i no nothing about css, is there another way to link an image here that the template language will work with?

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

css unless directly on the template does not run through django's template renderer. You need to use the url,

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

so mysite.com/static/css/mycss.css

or image depending on how your myproject/static looks like (STATICFILES_DIRS / STATIC_ROOT)

mysite.com/static/images/myimage.png

Answer (score 1):

CSS files are not processed by the django template system.  So your second snippet with relative path is the right way to link to images/fonts.